# Why game does not see the input of the "R" key?

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

The game does not see the input of the "R" key, I use a

```
{
    if keyboard_check_pressed(ord("R")) && global.died = true{
        global.died = false;
            room_restart();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this within a Script? If so, is the script used by an Object Event? The code seem to look fine otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, Its script, and he used by object event

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a current version of GameMaker, the code in a script should be in a function, e.g.

```
function scrCheckRestart() {
    if keyboard_check_pressed(ord("R")) && global.died = true{
        global.died = false;
            room_restart();
    }
}
```